# How to force https redirect on heroku with express 4.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

I don't understand why my following code does not accomplish this? Can someone explain where I am going wrong? All http requests should be redirected to https on heroku, but not on localhost. If someone could point me to an example of this working I would really appreciate it. I feel like this should be very simple and straightforward.

```
var app = express();

var https_redirect = function () {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
      if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
      } else {
        return next();
      }
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  };
};
app.use(https_redirect());

var server = app.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

I did some searching already and it looks like what I have should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your middleware's `req, res, next` params are being lost by having been wrapped by an outer function.

Try this:

```
var https_redirect = function(req, res, next) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {
            return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    } else {
        return next();
    }
};

app.use(https_redirect);
```

Comment: Very simple, thanks! Not that it would affect performance measurably, but it seems to me it would make more sense to put the If statement around this whole section of code instead of adding middleware that is a noop outside of production.

Comment: This works for me, but redirects to port 80, which doesn't work. How can I redirect to 443?

Answer (score 2):

The open source [express-force-ssl](https://github.com/battlejj/express-force-ssl) library checks `X-Forwarded-Proto` and ought to work with Heroku. [The code is very simple.](https://github.com/battlejj/express-force-ssl/blob/master/index.js)